# Windows 8 c# save a camera's picture on local storage

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, local-storage

I'm new to C# and I want to create an application metro who can take picture and save themself in localstorage. I know, i need to use isolated storage but i really don't understand how to use it for image. I saw a lot of examples for string but not for picture.

If anyone know how to do it ? Actually i take a picture and i ask the user to record it where he wants. But I want an auto record after the user take the picture. This my code for the moment :

```
private async void Camera_Clicked(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {       
        CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
        camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
        StorageFile photo = await camera.
                                  CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.
                                               OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            ImageSource.Source = bmp;
            ImageSource.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            appSettings[photoKey] = photo.Path;


            FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add
                                  ("jpeg image", new List<string>() { ".jpeg" });

            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New picture";

            StorageFile ff = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (ff != null)
            {
                await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(ff);                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need to do is to replace File Picker logic with retrieving of StorageFile object in Local folder, for example like this:

```
private async void Camera_Clicked(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{       
   CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
   camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
   StorageFile photo = await camera.
                          CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

   if (photo != null)
   {
      var targetFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("some_file_name.jpg");
      if (targetFile != null)
      {
         await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);                 
      }
   }
}
```